# Uncaught TypeError: URL.createObjectURL: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 1-argument overloads

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to provide the administrators with a CSV-download on button click. The ajax call used to do so, gets triggered by a button in the Wordpress Admin-Dashboard. For the AJAX-part I mostly copied the code from Jonathan Amend's answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post). With a few adjustments and the serverside set up, I've been trying to download the csv-file. The download window doesn't pop up and the console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: URL.createObjectURL: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 1-argument overloads.
```

By Argument 1 it can only mean the `blob` which gets sent from the serverside. The documentation for URL.createObjectURL says:

> object:
> A File, Blob, or MediaSource object to create an object URL for.

Putting that together it can only mean, that the `blob` data received from the server has incorrect format. When I log the `typeof blob` to console, it says `"string"`.

This is part of the code used on the serverside:

```
    // Reading arguments, sanitize and validate data
    // Query database and store in $results (as assoc_array)
    $delimiter = ";";
    $file = fopen("php://output","w");

    $cols_printed = false;
    foreach($results as $row) {

        if (!$cols_printed){

            // FPUT 1: Write Aliases of query to file once
            fputcsv($file, array_keys($row), $delimiter);
            $cols_printed = true;
        }

        // FPUT 2: Write values to file
        fputcsv($file, array_values($row), $delimiter);
    }
    // Close file, sending headers
```

If I comment out FPUT 2, then the csv can be downloaded (of course with only the column names and no data). The `typeof blob` changes to `"object"`.
I tried converting the whole `blob` explicitely before calling the `URL.createObjectURL` in JS, letting me successfully download the file without error, but the actual rows were nowhere to be seen. So what makes the 2nd FPUT diffrent?

EDIT 1: I've done some further testing. If I take the `FPUT1` out of the if-statement, it throws the same error. Within the .php script there are no other `var_dump`, `print_r` or `echo` who could produce this output. Even when putting an `echo "test";` at the very end of this file, the two newlines come still after. I could fix this by moving all code into the main plugin.php file. However, the client still thinks of the response as a string, despite changing my `SELECT`to a single INT column.

Comment: Are you sure your PHP code isn’t producing any errors, have you actually verified that? Have you inspected the request in your browser dev tools, and checked what the response code was?

Comment: I don't know how to verify that. In dev tools however, this POST-call returns status 200 as well as all desired data under the 'response' tab. Whatever the reason, the response starts with 2 newlines. Copying and inspecting the response to notepad showed no special characters or such, simply CRLF.

Comment: I don’t see why such newlines should prevent the download part from working, but either way, those must be coming from your PHP script. And I don’t see how commenting out the line under `// FPUT 2` should even change anything about that - you wrote the headers to the file first in any case under `// FPUT 1`, so if those newlines result in any way _from_ `// FPUT 2`, then I’d expect them to come _after_ the header line, not at the very start of the file … You’re gonna need to do some more debugging here, i don’t think anyone can tell what is going on here from the outside.